# How can I create a Wordpress dropdown menu for mobile using my categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, drop-down-menu, navigation

Here is the website I am working on.

www.sunsetwomenssoccer.com

I am having problems with the mobile nav that is set up with the theme. So instead I was wondering what the best route would be to set up a simple dropdown menu displaying my categories (nav in desktop view). Again, my navigation does not consist of pages, but rather categories.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_dropdown_categories()` function may help you.

For example, use:

```
<li id="categories">
    <h2><?php _e('Categories:'); ?></h2>
    <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
    <div>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=1&hierarchical=1'); ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
    </div>
    </form>
</li>
```